# Get a Sum of ONLY duplicate values

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula, sumifs

If there a way to use a sumif combined with a countif?

for example if I have

```
TransactionNo|NumberToSum
    1        |  
    1        |  9
    2        |  6
    3        |  3
    4        |  
    4        |  4
    5        |  6
    6        |  4
    7        |  
    7        |  9
    8        |  7
    9        |  4
    10       |  
    10       |  1
    11       |  3
    12       |  6
```

My result would be: ***23***

because the values `1,4,7,10` are duplicated, so I need to sum the `NumberToSum` of those `9,4,9,1` in this case.

Ideally I would like somethings along the lines of `=SumIf(A:A,Count>1,B:B)`

Where B is summed if the count of A inside of A:A is > 1.

but `=SUMIF(A:A,COUNT(A:A)>1,B:B)` does not work.

***NOTE:*** the Data is *NOT* sorted as it appears in my example.

If I wanted to do it in VBA one quick way could be:

```
Sub sumdups()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim Sum As Long

Set rng = [A2:A17]

For Each rng2 In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A17"), rng2.Value) > 1 Then
        Sum = Sum + rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next rng2
End Sub
```

Another option I have tried is to add a column with the formula

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,B2,"")
```

Then sum the helper column, but I am hoping there is a simple formula that can do the same all in one cell.

I am really just looking for a faster formula that can be entered in a single cell, without the need for any additional calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula works for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIF(A1:A100,A1:A100)>1),(B1:B100))
```

or for entire column (a little bit slower):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>1),(B:B))
```

Comment: These froze excel, I have over 800,000 rows to process. Is it possible to use this formula ONLY on visible cells? Non Filtered rows? Like a `Subtotal()` function?

Comment: @user2125348 Almost any formula would slow excel down at 800k rows, even a macro. If performance is that important, you might consider using a database instead, as you're also approaching Excel's row limit (at least, the default limit of excel 2007/2010 AFAIK)

Comment: @user2125348, `it possible to use this formula ONLY on visible cells?` - no, it's not possible

Comment: @Jerry The rest of the data is in a SQL Server, but I use and modify it VERY frequently though and need the flexibility that Excel offers. this is a very small portion of the data. I have all static daily calculations done in .Net. Regardless a Macro runs in seconds as I filter all the data then Loop only `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`  The calculation and Select statements it would require would be INSANELY complex in order to get some of the data out of these tables that I can do in minutes with excel. As the actual data structure is very poorly written by an outside development team.

Comment: @user2125348, PowerPivot ([link1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-en/excel-help/HA102837110.aspx) and [link2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx)) may be interesting for you. And it's absolutely free

Comment: @simoco I use it all the time. but thanks anyway for the links

Comment: If you want to use on Non Filtered rows then it's easy with a helper column, e.g. in Z2 copied down column `=SUBTOTAL(9,B2)` then change simoco's suggested formula to `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100)>1),Z2:Z100)`

Comment: @barryhoudini I have a much faster solution if I am to use a helper

Comment: Sorry, in fact I don't think my suggestion works anyway. To confirm, are you looking to sum only visible rows where there is more than one row for a specific transaction number visible? [so there might be multiple rows for a transaction number, but only one visible - so it shouldn't be summed].